# Combine multiple DOM element variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I usually define all my jQuery variables at the top of the module I am working on. There sometimes becomes a case when I would like to combine the variables to effect them both. So for example, imagine a case where I have defined them like so:

```
$myVar = $('#my-var');
$myOtherVar = $('my-other-var');
```

If I want to remove them both from the DOM, I would have to do the following:

```
$myVar.remove();
$myOtherVar.remove();
```

Is there a way I could create another variable and combine them? So I wouldn't have to do this:

```
$('#my-var, #my-other-var).remove();
```

Thanks.

Comment: use add() like `$myOtherVar.add($myVar).remove()`

Comment: I think he means he wants to append all the elements he wants to remove in one statement and then perform the 'remove-all-at-once' to reduce operations on the DOM... I don't really know since im not a huge Jquery guy, but something array based sounds like your best bet.

Comment: Also i hope you're not polluting the global scope and using IIFY's with your modules :P